# Auto Complete for Malayalam Search

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, search, autocomplete

I want to have a search for malayalam words using PHP, MYSQL and JQUERY. I want auto complete for search box.  I have tried all auto search things . No use. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: What are you looking for ~ malayalam words or autocomplete widget?

Comment: I want auto complete for Malayalam words from database

Comment: If you have the data, then you can bind it to any autocomplete control. Make sure that the fonts are loaded. Did you try biding data?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand as much as possible from your question, seems that you want to implement a search for Malayalam language.

Here's what you can do:

- Set data type of the column which you want to perform search on, to
  `varchar`, character set to `utf16_unicode_ci`.